# Destination suggestion by searching the name in searchbar SKMAPS

Tags: ios, objective-c, skmaps

Is it possible to search for an address using searchbar in skmaps offline package. I had downloaded and included the offline city package from the demo project.

Now I have to select my destination point for my navigation by searching the destination's name in search bar which provides a list of suggestions for my destination.

If not possible, please tell me the alternate way to achieve this.

Comment: Hi Mohanraj. Was the answer below of use to you? It is customary here to accept, vote upon, or reply to answers on our own questions.

Answer (score 0):

In 2.5.1 SDK, we support only multi-step search. The existing possibilities: "Address search - offline", "Nearby search" and "Category search” - you can check them in our demo project in the menu options and our getting started documentation: http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/ios#sec26